# Motion tracking footage from 24 DSLR cameras fails, but why?

Tags: tracking

I am driving a bullet time rig with 24 cameras and now I want to put 3D objects into the scenery.

The 24 frames were shot in a studio with a clean white cove where markers were put all over the walls, to make tracking easy. Now I manually added the tracking points to the footage but blender fails to solve the camera. I suppose with such markers it should be possible. However a lot of the markers cannot be solved.

Now since the footage is made with a bullet time rig, a lot of the markers aren't visible in all frames.

I'd really appreciate, if someone could give me a hint how to resolve the camera and which settings would be best when taking the shot.

[Here is the project with my markers and with the 24 JPGs.](http://www.for-downloads-only.de/temp/24DSLR.zip)

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Your tracking is inaccurate. Trackers are dancing all over. Fix that first.

[image]

[image]

The most important part is that your track elements in the foreground and some elements in the background. The difference (parallax) is the trick to solving a scene in 3D. But without accurate tracking you will get nowhere.